# MySQL sort by grouped date in joined table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a table, called `Posts`, and a second table, called `Comments`. These are linked by an `id` column in the posts table, and a `postid` column in the comments table.

Both tables have a `date` column, which is the date when they were posted. I want to be able to sort my posts based on the newest activity, so they should be sorted by the post's date (if there are no comments) or the *newest* comment's date.

In order to do this, I've constructed this simple query:

```
SELECT Posts.id FROM Posts
INNER JOIN Comments ON Posts.id = Comments.postid
ORDER BY Comments.date ASC
```

Unfortunately, this has a very obvious problem. If there are no comments on a post, it will be ignored. If there are multiple comments on a post, it will show up multiple times in the results.

How can I construct a query to satisfy these requirements?

Comment: So add `Posts.date ASC` to your `ORDER BY`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a `LEFT JOIN`, that returns all rows from `Posts`, and rows from `Comments` only when the JOIN succeedes. If the join doesn't succeed because there are no comments with `comments.postid=posts.id`, you still get all values from `Posts`, but values from `Comments` will be Null.

You then have to use `GROUP BY`, so you will get only one row for each ID, and you can use MAX() aggregate function to get the maximum date in comments table.

If there are no comments, `max(comments.date)` will be Null, so COALESCE will return `Posts.date` instead.

And the final query is this:

```
SELECT Posts.id
FROM Posts LEFT JOIN Comments
     ON Posts.id = Comments.postid
GROUP BY Posts.id
ORDER BY coalesce(max(Comments.date),Posts.date) ASC
```

Comment: Great, thanks, I didn't know about coalesce. Could you briefly explain why the `GROUP BY` clause is necessary here? I admittedly don't really know how it works.

Answer (score 1):

You need a left outer join to take into account that there may be no comments:

```
SELECT Posts.id
FROM Posts left JOIN
     Comments
     ON Posts.id = Comments.postid
group by posts.id
ORDER BY coalesce(max(Comments.date), posts.date) ASC
```